# R Shiny : enable JavaScript in app with custom URL

Tags: javascript, r, url, shiny, shinyapps

I'm running a ShinyApp with a bit of JavaScript (eg : to get user's geolocation).
We are using Shiny custom URL for this app so the orignal webpage is displayed inside an iframe when you visit our app through the custom URL.
As far as I understood, running JavaScript inside an iframe is not allowed, which causes loss of functionalities in our app, like geolocation. Is there a way to allow JavaScript in this iframe from my original app.R code ? Or another way to get my scripts running ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's going to be hard to help you. Please, provide something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Observable](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/ojs/) in a Quarto document? You can run javascript-like cells inside an R document. R studio can then knit your code into an html page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).